# Hardware-independent recovery key similar to Bitlocker?

Tags: filevault, t2

I've been doing a bit of research about FileVault and APFS recently, but it still confuses me. I learned about the two types of recovery keys for FileVault, personal recovery key and institutional recovery key. According to what I read, the personal one only works on the same device (if the Mac is broken, access will be impossible) and the institutional one requires an MDM, a PKI, and needs to be configured before the volume is encrypted.

Is there any device-independent recovery key that I can export from an unlocked volume and use for unlocking on any device?

Windows Bitlocker has this function and it is very handy, because in many situation you do not have to mess around with protectors or cryptousers, TPM/T2-chips and similar device-specific mechanisms. One basically exports the AES-key of the drive or something fully equivalent.

I read about a "secure token" but I did not really understand it. Could this be what I am thinking about?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? For what do you need the key on another device? All you should ever need is the password to unlock the volume, surely?

Comment: @benwiggy Well, my current use case/problem is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422994/dd-image-of-target-mode-disk-cannot-be-unlocked-cryptousers-lost

but my basic intention is to understand and that I hope that it can be much easier in many cases than messsing around with fdesetup, cryotousers and such. Hardware my always fail all out of the sudden.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.m3datarecovery.com/mac-bitlocker/

Comment: @SamAndrew81 I do not understand how this related to my question/problem, the tool on the website that you reference to is created to access BitLocker-Partitions on Mac, why is this relevant for this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Way we manage this at work is we use MDM to enforce and monitor for the presence of a unique key that gets escrowed. Unfortunately, if you support Intel and Apple Silicon Macs and ones with and without the T2 chip and Secure Enclave, there are differences in implementation and levels of harness on macOS that may not translate to someone looking to take their bitlocker knowledge and apply it directly to another platform.

We also ensure we have backups with keys we manage so even if a Mac gets wiped or locked, the files themselves are not lost due to a failure to have an admin account or key escrowed for decryption of data. You can avoid this problem entirely if you focus on securing the data and not keys to unlock one copy of the data.

The [secure token](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/managing-filevault-sec8447f5049/web) connects a user space key with the private keys that never leave the Secure Enclave on newer hardware. Basically the one grants access to load the other securely. Apple has very dense but also very approachable documentation on this in their platform security papers and website:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/security/welcome/web

Comment: Thanks.
Your 1st paragraph is about the institutional recovery key, isn't it? (MDM-requirement and such)
Is your point in the second paragraph to backup the data such that in case the device (and t2 chip) is lost/damaged no relevant user data is lost? From a users perspective that might be right, but such backups will hardly be useful for scenarios such as computer forensics.

Is your point in the 3rd paragraph that for security reasons Apple does not want the legitimate user/owner to be able to extract hardware-independent decryption keys so my "wish" cannot become true?!

Comment: We take a week plus to map this out at work @dsfsdfdsf23 there are a lot of variables to cover it all or make it simpler than it is. I don’t think “Apple wants”anything since there are competing teams, customers, versions at play. It’s more what was implemented and what choices we make IMO.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your tags, I assume we're talking about an internal drive on a modern Mac with a T2 (or newer) running a recent version of macOS.

I'll answer your question directly: No, there is no device-independent recovery key you can export from an unlocked volume and use for unlocking on any device.

If it were possible to export such a key, the act of doing so would lessen the security of the system.

Could Apple have made it possible to do so anyways? - Certainly. It is a choice to make the FileVault system function the way it does.